# Representing Recursive Summations

Tags: python, math

Coding problem:
When I receive the input 2 I want to receive the output 2 as my base case. Any inputs higher than this will create summations. Sorry in advance I don't have a high enough reputation to post images, but I'm still using E as short hand for summation and [x,y] for the summations range. Example:

```
Input: 3
Output: 
3+2+1
OR
E[i=1,3] i

Input: 4
Output: 
4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1 
OR
E[i=1,4] i + E[i=1,3] i + E[i=1,2] i + E[i=1,1] i

Input: 5 
Output: 
5+4+3+2+1+4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1+4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1+3+2+1+2+1+1+2+1+1+1 
OR
E[i=1,5] i + E[i=1,4] i + E[i=1,3] i + E[i=1,2] i + E[i=1,1] i
+ E[i=1,4] i + E[i=1,3] i + E[i=1,2] i + E[i=1,1] i
+ E[i=1,3] i + E[i=1,2] i + E[i=1,1] i
+ E[i=1,2] i + E[i=1,1] i
+ E[i=1,1] i
```

And so on. Input should add a summation and use said input as the end point for the first summation. The first idea I had was to recursively add for loops since we generally represent summations as for loops with a range. I'm sure this is possible but I haven't had any success with the problem. Another approach I had with to represent the summations algebraically. The first summation would equal (n^2 + n)/2 and I could keep repeating this equation until I converted every summation. This approach makes the most sense to me but I've had no success with this either. If I'm missing something and representing repeating summations in code is standard or anyone has any ideas they could throw my way I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm very stuck and I hope you guys find this as interesting as I do.

Comment: Why is `Input: 3` `3+2+1` and not `3+2+1+2+1+1` while `input 4` is `4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Input 3 will have a total of 1 sum. 4 will have a total of 2 sums. 5 will have a total of 3 sums. So beginning with input 3, with only 1 summation will be 1+2+3

Comment: @RoryDaulton you're right about the number changes so I've edited it to reflect them, thank you. And that's a good idea I'll try to add a graphic soon

Comment: @RoryDaulton to explain the input 2 better: since 5 as a total of 3 summations, 4 will have a total of 2, 3 will have a total of 1, and 2 will have no summations but it will still have "i". Since this input is 2 then all that is left is to output 2

Comment: Lol thanks and I understand I do as well. And yes it would also make sense for the input of 2 to output 0 but in this case we want the output 2. In truth this problem actually arose naturally and might actually have a use case if my idea about some other math is correct. If you want to know what exactly this can be used for I don't mind explaining but for now this is the math/coding barrier I've been stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is recursive code that solves your problem. It gives your desired result `2` for the base case of an input of `2`--though I disagreed with that choice I now agree with it. It returns an error for any value less than `2`. My code first builds a list of the integers then prints your desired summation--that makes it easier for you to do something with those numbers, such as actually summing those numbers. I also included test code for pytest--if my input line is commented out, my code passes the tests.

```
def levelslist(n):
    def levelslist_recurse(start, level):
        if level == 0:
            return [start]
        return [val for newstart in range(start, 0, -1)
                for val in levelslist_recurse(newstart, level - 1)]
    assert n >= 2
    return levelslist_recurse(n, n-2)


def levelssummation(n):
    return "+".join(map(str, levelslist(n)))


n = int(input("N? ").strip())
print(levelssummation(n))


def test_levelslist():
    assert levelssummation(2) == "2"
    assert levelssummation(3) == "3+2+1"
    assert levelssummation(4) == "4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1"
    assert levelssummation(5) == ("5+4+3+2+1+4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1"
                                  "+4+3+2+1+3+2+1+2+1+1+3+2+1+2+1+1+2+1+1+1")
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Running through this by hand seems to give correct outputs. I'll get back to you soon after I've tested the code more properly

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: I have edited my code. It now hides the recursive routine from the casual programmer, makes it easier to use the list of numbers or the string of summation, and adds code for testing. The downside is that my code is now a little more complicated.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: I just made another edit. I changed my mind and agree with you that the result for `N=2` is `2`, not zero. My code now reflects that, there is now no special case for `N=2`, and the code is simpler. This new code still passes all the tests. That said, the "base case" for the recursion is not `N == 2` but rather `level == 0`, which admittedly does happen when `N` is zero but also happens at other times.